# How to create metrics on static website pages in Azure by CLI

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-monitoring

[The official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal) instruct how to enable metrics on static website pages in Azure in the portal. The chart is able to be pinned in a dashboard there.

However, the method is not fit with my need.

1. It cannot be filtered by folder or file. All transactions and egress belong to the same $web only. If there are two sub folders and I would like to view their visit counts separately, the metrics do not help.
2. The portal method is not an automation method. The metric graph cannot be created by [az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest).

How can I use scripting way to create a chart or log of Storage's static website's daily visit count breakdown by folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the slow reply, after searching everywhere, I figured out that it is **not supported** for folder, and as I said, it's not supported create a chart or log of Storage using CLI.